# How to hook the download dialog in a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-addon

I'm writing a Firefox extension and I need to hook the download dialog that comes up when the user tries to download a file.

In other words, I need a script-defined function to be notified *instead* of the dialog appearing as normal.

Where do I begin? I tried reading through the XPCOM API Reference... but [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications) is the closest thing I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override [nsIDownloadManagerUI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDownloadManagerUI) (by implementing it).

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that.