# How to catch file download event in Firefox Extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hook the download dialog in a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580937/how-to-hook-the-download-dialog-in-a-firefox-extension)

I have developed a Download Accelerator and now want to create a Firefox Extension for it.  What I need to know is when a file download is requested.  I have read about the 'observer-service' events such as 'dl-start'.  However, these events are fired after the default download dialog is displayed, I need to catch the download before the default.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to this question is what you are also looking for:
[How to hook the download dialog in a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580937/how-to-hook-the-download-dialog-in-a-firefox-extension)