# How to detect when a user start downloading a file in a browser?

Tags: c#, java, browser, download

I'm trying to understand (and possibly implement) how some file downloaders detect a download in my browser and automatically start downloading in replacement of the browser internal download module. Any idea how it's done especially related to C# or Java coding ?

Comment: Is Firefox the only browser you need to support?

Comment: of course no also IE,Safari,Opera and Chrome

Comment: Then I suggest you do your own research for each browser. Each one requires its own method from what I understand and have their own quirks. Please remember that SO is not your personal R&D service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, download managers are implemented as Extensions (plug-ins). A good starting place would be [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development)

Comment: +1  Also, take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580937/how-to-hook-the-download-dialog-in-a-firefox-extension  for Firefox specific example.