# Don't want IDM to catch my firefox plugin downloads

Tags: firefox, download, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, download-manager

I'm developing a FF extension which will be downloading zip files from server(s), saving to specific local location and unzipping the file.

But my problem is IDM plugin which is installed in my FF. Whenever I try to download a file from server IDM catches it and shows its download dialog.

I want to save file(s) at specific location (other than downloads dir), so I dont want IDM to catch it or else myPlugin will not get the file and download untill it gets file.

I guess IDM has implemented nslDownloadManager [How to hook the download dialog in a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580937/how-to-hook-the-download-dialog-in-a-firefox-extension) -------- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDownloadManagerUI?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIDownloadManagerUI

Should I implement this also to escape from IDM or any other downloader? I don't want to catch downloads; from; other than my plugin.

I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files#Downloading_files this function to download file. For testing purpose I press `Control` key to disable IDM plugin.

Can you please tell me what should I do to download zipped files from my plugin without getting caught in IDM???

Comment: When the IDM message appears, click CANCEL and it will be downloaded with your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporary disable IDM for single download you may hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>  button while clicking on the download link of zipped files to prevent IDM from taking the download.

Answer (score 0):

[Turn off the browser integration](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/options.html)

Comment: Well Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me how to turn off via code just for my download, manually I know how to do it.